# Vb.Net - Total de registro em ordem decrescente

Tags: vb.net, visual-basic-6

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]criei um projeto em VB.NET nele ao consultar pelo codigo me mostra o total de registro que aquele chamado tem, porém preciso que seja em ordem decrescente já que ao pesquisar meu formulário carrega sempre o último registro.

Segue o Código -

```
Private Sub CarregaTabela()

    ' ----- Pega a Qtd do registro de um chamado -------------

    stSQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS QTD FROM  PROVIDENCIA WHERE COD_OCORRENCIA = '" + txtCodOcorrencia.Text.PadLeft(10, "0") + "' "
    comCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(stSQL, conBase)
    comCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    darProvidencia = comCommand.ExecuteReader()

    darProvidencia.Read()
    dtx = Convert.ToInt32(darProvidencia("QTD"))

End Sub 

'----------- Páginação - posição dos botões  ----------------------------------------------------
Private Sub MovimentarRegistro(ByVal e As eRegistro)
    Select Case e
        Case eRegistro.Primeiro

            If posicao > 0 Then posicao -= 1

        Case eRegistro.Ultimo
            If posicao < (dtx - 1) Then posicao += 1
        Case Else
            posicao = dtx - 1
    End Select
End Sub
```

Att,

Answer (score 0):

Seria algo tipo:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), ID FROM TABELA GROUP BY ID ORDER BY ID DESC
```